# How do i call something out from my LocalStorage and make the thing dynamic

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am currently trying to stimulate a forum. And what i have done so far, is when a user asked a question

1. The topic and questions will be saved into an object and pushed into an array
2. On the main page, all the objects in the array will be displayed
3. I will be able to click on each of the displayed links.

But here comes the tricky part. How do i use one same HTML and change the code in it dynamically.

I know i call use a array[0].Question to change the content of the INNERHTML code. But i do not know how to make a specific array[Number] come out.

For example. If i have a array of length 0 - 4! And i want to call the array[0] when i clicked the first link. Followed by array[1] when i clicked the second link! How do i do it!

Another solution i found is the use of URL hash. However in order to use URL hash, i have to make 5 amount of pages if i want to make all my array object dynamic right?

Hopefully you guys understand what i mean!

Comment: *Hopefully you guys understand what i mean!* We don't. By the way, in English we capitalize the word "I".

Comment: Ok let me try to explain it again! It is really hard to explain this logic! What i want to do is depending on what the user clicks, display certain stuff! Is there any way to do that?

Comment: For example... If i were to let say have 3 different links. Each supposedly having to contain different content. Is it possible for me to change the data of the same page to 3 different content depending on which link the user clicks?

Comment: Yes, that is what all web applications do.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've gathered, you have an array of questions like

```
var questions = [{
  title: 'Question 1',
  description: 'something about Question 1'
}, {
  title: 'Question 2',
  description: 'something about Question 2'
}]
```

And you want to be able to show the description for each question without actually navigating to a new page. This is possible with plain javascript (cleaner with jQuery).

Here is a general plain js approach you can build on:

```js
var questions = [{
  title: 'Question 1',
  description: 'something about Question 1'
}, {
  title: 'Question 2',
  description: 'something about Question 2'
}]

var questionContainer = document.getElementById('questions');
var descriptionContainer = document.getElementById('description');
var contentContainer = document.getElementById('content');
var backBtn = document.getElementById('back-btn');

questions.forEach(function(question) {
  var q = document.createElement('div');
  q.innerText = question.title;
  q.className = 'question';
  q.addEventListener('click', function() {
    contentContainer.innerText = question.description;
    descriptionContainer.style.display = 'block';
    questionContainer.style.display = 'none';
  })
  questionContainer.appendChild(q);
})

backBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  descriptionContainer.style.display = 'none';
  questionContainer.style.display = 'block';
})
```

```css
.question:hover,
#back-btn:hover {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="questions"></div>

<div id="description" style="display: none;">
  <div id="back-btn">Back</div>
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

**Please note** This is fine for playing around, or a personal project. However, the end result is still "static" because you have a static array of questions you are storing on the front end. If you want this to be truly dynamic, you will have to store questions and all relevant details in some kind of database.